# Creating table with unknown headers with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a .json with unknown attributes and want to graph them. In my controller I have already extracted the headers and saved them as table_headers, from the doubleObjects Object. The data looks like this:

```
$scope.items = {[ 
...,
{doubleObjects: [{...}, {...}, ...]},
...,
]};
```

This is what I'm trying to output:

```
  <table style="width:100%" border="1px solid black">
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="y in table_headers">{{y}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in items.doubleObjects">
            <td ng-repeat="y in table_headers">{{x.y}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

So I would like the entire doubleObjects object to be tabulated. It wont let me do:

```
{{x.y}}
```

If I do:

```
{{x.measurement}}
```

or another attribute that is in doubleObjects then its all fine. But I cant ensure that the "measurement" attribute will be there. (For my test data it is.)

Thoughts and suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: have you tried to access values using this way: x[y]?

Comment: No, I tried {{x[$index]}} but that wasn't doing what I wanted. x[y] was perfect thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use x and y that way `{{x.y}}` use it this way `{{x[y]}}` or like the other way  shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogthxhbe/1/) which shows both possibilities. I stated both possibilities, as I didn't really understood what you are looking for and I'm not allowed to comment your post.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in items.doubleObjects">
    <td ng-repeat="y in table_headers">{{x.measurement}}.{{y}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="y in table_headers">{{x[y]}}</td>
</tr>
```